# How can I make a textbox readonly using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using a combination of knockout and jquery and I would like to know how I can make a textbox readonly in either knockout or jquery

Comment: `$(yourTextBox).prop('readonly', true);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please don't post answers as comments

Comment: He most likely knew it was about to be closed as a duplicate and was trying to help the OP without getting in the way of the garbage collector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there you have not shown us what you have tried so far, however, I have listed a knockout and jquery example that might be useful to you. You can also have a look at this link for further clarification.

```
<!-- ko if: if your condition is met  -->
  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" data-bind="value:  texboxValue" id="textboxID"  />
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: if your condition is not met -->
  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" data-bind="value:  texboxValue" id="textboxID" textboxName" readonly />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Then on the jQuery side:

```
// this will make you textbox readonly
$("#textboxID").attr('readonly', 'readonly');

// this will remove the readonly attribute from your text box read/writeable
$("#textbox").removeAttr('readonly');
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('id/class').attr('readonly', true);
```